# How to transfer data from mysql to oracle using camel

Tags: mysql, oracle, spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to copy data from Mysql (5.1.37) to an Oracle database (11) using Camel and Spring. The configuration looks like this:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
 <route>
  <from uri="direct:start" />
  <to uri="sql:select id, name, description from user?dataSourceRef=fromDataSource" />
  <to uri="sql:insert into user (id, name, description) values (#, #, #)?dataSourceRef=toDataSource"/>
 </route>
</camelContext>
```

I'm running it using the following code:

```
public void fetchUsers() throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = (CamelContext) SpringUtil.getBean("camelContext");
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.start();
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "test");
}
```

However, I'm getting an exception:

```
10:04:24,208 ERROR [main] DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UNISTHDW177-55800-1338278663095-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-UNISTHDW177-55800-1338278663095-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [{id=1, name=Carl, description=Developer}, {id=2, name=Lars, description=Developer}]]
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [{id=1, name=Carl, description=Developer}, {id=2, name=Lars, description=Developer}]]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1237)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:282)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:333)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:324)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:324)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:131)
    at com.unibet.finance.reporting.camel.GordiumFetcherTest.camelShouldFetchGordiumAttributes(GordiumFetcherTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$1.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$1.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer.process(SqlProducer.java:48)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    ... 70 more
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are the datasources setup? Transactional?

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? And what versions of the JDBC driver. I suspect the JDBC driver may not support metadata, since the AbstractMethodError is thrown

Comment: I'm using Camel 2.9.2, and Oracle drivers 10.2.0.3.0. I also tried using 11.2.0.3.0 but the same problem occurred there. The problem seem to be with the `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement` class. It simply doesn't have a `getParameterMetaData()` method which Camel is trying to call (at SqlProducer.java line 50) and its super classes don't seem to implement it either.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your JDBC driver implements the older version of JDBC API then the one available in JRE you use to run your application (and which is required by Camel). You need JDBC API version >= 3 in this case.

The problem should be solved be updating your Oracle driver to the latest version (supporting your database).

You wrote in the comment that you had already tried to update the driver version (with no effect). Probably you got an older version of Oracle driver somewhere in the lib/ext directory in your application server. Probably you are using Maven to Fetch Oracle JDBC driver while another driver instance is provided by application server.

The is not the Camel problem, but JDBC driver and server classpath problem. Fix your driver classpath issue and Camel will do his job :) .

Comment: I'm not using it through a server, I'm trying it in a test. I replaced the driver with the latest one (11.2.0.3.0), and debugged the test again. The PreparedStatement instance is a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement and it still doesn't implement the getParameterMetaData() method, and I get an Exception. So I guess this is an Oracle issue. Does this mean I simply can't use Camel to insert data in an Oracle database? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Oracle provides several ojdbc_.jar drivers - dedicated for the particular JDK version. You probably not using the right one. If you run Java 6, make sure that you use ojdbc6 driver.

Comment: As far as I remember Oracle states that it supports JDBC3 fully since certain version of their driver. That would mean that it is possible to choose a driver that implements the getParameterMetaData() method.